# Re-adding Div To DOM Is Causing Styling Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, tailwind-css

I am trying to achieve a specific layout on my webpage where the UI elements adapt smoothly between large (lg) and medium (md) screens. I have successfully achieved the first layout on a large screen:

[image: First large screen layout]

However, to achieve the second layout in medium screens, I am wrapping the images in a div which I remove when the screen resizes down to md, and I'm using JavaScript to add it back when the screen is resized back up to lg. It works correctly on the first load, but when I resize from lg to md and back to lg, the layout appears differently than the initial layout:

[image: Second medium screen layout]

large screen after resizing from lg to md and back to lg:

[image: Third large screen layout]

I don't know what could be causing the difference in layout despite having the same DOM structure. Here is the relevant code (I'm using blade to pull in images, so this is just an example code):

```html
<div class="mx-auto mt-16 max-w-2xl lg:max-w-none">
    <div class="mx-auto bg-white mt-6 lg:h-[40rem] overflow-hidden">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-6 gap-12">
            <div class="lg:col-span-2" id="myDiv">
                <div class="col-span-1 test">
                    <!-- Image 1 -->
                    <div class="flex justify-center">
                        <x-curator-glider
                            class="h-full"
                            media="{{ $keyHighlightSection2Images[0]['image'] }}"
                            format="webp"
                            loading="lazy"
                            quality="80"
                            width="800"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-span-1">
                    <!-- Image 2 -->
                    <div class="flex justify-center">
                        <x-curator-glider
                            class="h-full"
                            media="{{ $keyHighlightSection2Images[1]['image'] }}"
                            format="webp"
                            loading="lazy"
                            quality="80"
                            width="800"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-span-1 lg:col-span-2">
                <!-- Image 3 (middle) -->
                <div class="flex justify-center lg:mt-48">
                    Image goes here
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-span-1">
                <!-- Image 4 -->
                <div class="flex justify-center">
                    Image goes here
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-span-1">
                <!-- Image 5 -->
                <div class="flex justify-center mb-16 lg:mb-0">
                    Image goes here
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    // Function to add/remove the div based on screen size
    function adjustDivOnScreenSize() {
        var screenWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');

        if (screenWidth <= 1024) {
            if (div) {
                var parent = div.parentNode;
                while (div.firstChild) {
                    parent.insertBefore(div.firstChild, div);
                }
                parent.removeChild(div);
            }
        } else {
            var parent = div.parentNode;
            var innerHtml = div.innerHTML;
            var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newDiv.id = 'myDiv';
            newDiv.className = 'lg:col-span-2'; // Set the appropriate CSS grid class
            newDiv.innerHTML = innerHtml;
            parent.insertBefore(newDiv, div);
            div.remove();
        }
    }


    function test() {
        var screenWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;

        if (screenWidth > 1024) {
            // Check if the div with id "myDiv" already exists
            var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

            if (!myDiv) {
                // Get a reference to the div with class "test"
                var testDiv = document.querySelector('.test');

                // Create a new div element for the wrapper
                myDiv = document.createElement('div');
                myDiv.id = 'myDiv';

                // Append the wrapper div to the parent element of the div with class "test"
                testDiv.parentElement.insertBefore(myDiv, testDiv);

                // Move the div with class "test" inside the wrapper div
                myDiv.appendChild(testDiv);
            }
        }
    }

    // Call the function on page load and window resize
    window.addEventListener('load', adjustDivOnScreenSize);
    window.addEventListener('resize', test);
    window.addEventListener('resize', adjustDivOnScreenSize);
</script>
```

Comment: What layout are you trying to achieve when the screen size is md or smaller? It may be possible to get the same effect using CSS and avoid JS altogether.

Comment: The second image on my post is what I achieve on md screen. On anything smaller it will be 1 image per row. I don't think it is possible to not include javascript in my scenario. The way I need it to display on lg screen requires a div wrapped around the images, whereas when I need 2 images per row in md, I need to remove that div in order to achieve 2 images on the 1st row, 2 on 2nd and 1 on 3rd.

Comment: Comparing the DOM structure on page load with the DOM structure after the div is removed and then re-added when adjusting the screen from large, to smaller and then back to large, they are identical. I don't know if tailwind css maybe doesn't take effect if you add the code back into the DOM using javascript.